# How do I answer on performing operation on large files in an interview?

Tags: algorithm, large-files

How would you get all of the unique IDs out of a single file? What if it was a very large file?

or

Suppose you have a large file with lots of words. How would you find the unique words and their count?

I am to assume that the number of unique words can be as large as a billion

Answer (score 0):

Accurate: use lots of memory.

Estimate: [Approximate Counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_counting_algorithm), [Linear Counting](http://dblab.kaist.ac.kr/Publication/pdf/ACM90_TODS_v15n2.pdf), or [HyperLogLog Counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog) etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using efficient data structures like tries, HashMaps, etc. As you said, it is a big file read part of the file at a time and process it, then continue with rest of the file ..